# FTP as folder/webdisk

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Is there any way for filezilla(or any other program) to make a folder that is a live ftp folder and any changes I make automatically go to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer supports this very well. You can use it to browse your FTP site and make changes: create/rename/delete directories and files.
Use the following syntax to connect:

```
ftp://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@YOUR_FTP_SITE
```

Then if you want to reflect the changes to a website, use a dynamic language for the rendering of your website. At each reload of the page of your website you would be able to show the changes in the FTP backend. If you do not want any reload of the page, then you need to have to have some timer & AJAX functionnalities in place in order to constantly check the ftp folder changes and reflect them if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I want to be able to edit with dreamweaver without having to upload back every time. I could do this on a local server but the mysql settings are different compared to my hosting and I would have to change some settings.

Answer (score 1):

On mac:
Get server IP address,
In browser type
ftp://IP_ADDRESS_HERE
Hit enter

Answer (score 0):

I use [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/). It's brililant, because it gives you a new drive letter that's mapped to your ftp site. Anything you change on the new drive is reflected live on your server. It'll work on ftp, sftp, ssh, whatever connection you throw at it.